# Problema con TwoWay Binding en aplicación para Windows Phone 8.1, MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, mvvm

Estoy desarrollando una App para un sistema de ventas básico utilizando **MVVM**, pero tengo problemas para guardar los datos que se ingresan desde la vista.

La vista:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="NameText"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Header="Nombre:"
             Style="{StaticResource RegisterTextBoxStyle}"
             Text="{Binding Product.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="UnitCombo"
              Grid.Row="3"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Header="Unidad:"
              PlaceholderText="Elige la medida"
              Style="{StaticResource RegisterComboBoxStyle}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UnitsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedUnit, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="CostText"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="4"
             Header="Costo:"
             Style="{StaticResource RegisterTextBoxStyle}"
             Text="{Binding Product.Cost, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="PriceText"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="4"
             Header="Precio:"
             Style="{StaticResource RegisterTextBoxStyle}"
             Text="{Binding Product.Price, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <ToggleSwitch x:Name="ActiveToggle"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="5"
                  Style="{StaticResource RegisterToggleSwithStyle}"
                  IsOn="{Binding Product.Active, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

La vista utiliza el comando **SaveProduct** para guardar los datos ingresados en la vista, y se llama desde:

```
        <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Añadir" Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}"/>
```

He establecido mi **DataContext** desde el archivo cs de la vista:

```
public AddProduct()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ProductListViewModel();
    }
```

**ProductListViewModel**:

```
namespace BillingShop.ViewModel
{
    public class ProductListViewModel : ViewModelBase, INavigable
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
    private DelegateCommand _saveProduct;
    public bool IsUpdating { get; set; }
    public ProductViewModel Product { get; set; }
    public Visibility UpdatingVisibility => (IsUpdating || Items == null || Items.Count == 0) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

    public ProductListViewModel()
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            return;
        }
        _saveProduct = new DelegateCommand(SaveCommand_Executed);
    }

    #region Product Members

    private string _unit;
    public string SelectedUnit
    {
        get { return _unit; }
        set
        {
            _unit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #endregion


    public IEnumerable<RegisteredUnits> UnitsSource => Enum.GetValues(typeof(RegisteredUnits)).Cast<RegisteredUnits>();

    public ICommand SaveCommand => _saveProduct;

    private void SaveCommand_Executed()
    {
        var product = new Product
        {
            Name = Product.Name,
            Unit = Product.Unit,
            Cost = Convert.ToDouble(Product.Cost),
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(Product.Price),
            Active = Convert.ToBoolean(Product.Active)
        };
        ProductManager.SaveProduct(product);
    }

    public void PopulateProductViewModel(ProductViewModel entry)
    {
        Product = entry;
        OnPropertyChanged("Product");
    }
    public Product GetProduct()
    {
        return Product?.GetProduct();
    }
}
```

}

**ProductViewModel**:

```
public class ProductViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public List<SalesDetails> SalesDetail { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ProductViewModel(Product item)
    {
        Update(item);
    }
    public void Update (Product item)
    {
        Id = item.ID;
        Name = item.Name;
        Unit = item.Unit;
        Cost = item.Cost;
        Price = item.Price;
        Active = item.Active;
        SalesDetail = item.SalesDetail;
    }

    public Product GetProduct()
    {
        return new Product
        {
            ID = Id,
            Name = Name,
            Unit = Unit,
            Cost = Cost,
            Price = Price,
            Active = Active,
            SalesDetail = SalesDetail
        };
    }
}
```

Cuando se ejecuta el comando de **SaveProduct**, la clase **Product** aparece como **null**, por lo que entiendo que no se guardaron los valores ingresados desde la vista en dicha clase.

Tengo entendido que **Mode=TwoWay** permite hacer un binding bidireccional, por lo que se deberían guardar los valores, o me equivoco?

Agradezco de antemano la respuesta de todos, y dejo a mano el repositorio público por si alguien desea revisar el código más detalladamente.
https://github.com/adoibarra/BillingShop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta inicializando la propiedad Product dentro del constructor de `ProductListViewModel`

```
public class ProductListViewModel
{
   public ProductListViewModel ()
   {
      Product = new ProductViewModel();
   }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me estaba faltando... Me salvaste la vida jajaja. Un fuerte abrazo...